# How do I make a menu link have an image next to the text?

Tags: css, image, menu, hyperlink

Like so: http://html5up.net/strongly-typed/
If you look at the menu, there's these little circles next to every menu link.
How exactly do I do that?

```
#menu a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #EEE;
line-height: 1;
margin-right: 45px;
text-shadow: 1px 2px 0 #111;
text-align: center;
```

That's the code I got the menu links so far, but when I try to add these little circles it just doesn't work :/ Nothing even shows up, and if something shows up, then its 1) not a circle and 2) not next to the link.

Help :/

Comment: It's an icon font probably in a pseudo-element or span

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `background-image` and the `:before` pseudo selector.

Here is a very simple example.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pys5K/1/)

**CSS**

```
li:before {
    content: "\A";
    background: url('http://placehold.it/30x30') no-repeat 0px 0px / 30px 30px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
}
```

Comment: @xDrac Depending on the size of the image, you need to add a margin. In my example, I use: `li {margin: 30px;}`

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the element with firebug or chrome's inspector you see the code:

```css
#nav > ul > li > a:before {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #878787;
    color: #e4e4e4;
    width: 1.65em; 
    height: 1.65em;
    border-radius: 1.65em;
    line-height: 1.65em;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0.125em 0.175em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
    margin-right: 0.75em;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out, background 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

The CSS seletor **':before'** inserts a element before the object **"#nav > ul > li > a"**

The hacks **'-moz-', '-webkit-', '-o-' and '-ms-'** are to make that code cross-browser.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work somehow.. here is the code I am using http://pastebin.com/hEUave38